# get Number of file in folder in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to get number of files in a folder but it give me below Exception

```
{System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Data\Programs\{6AF473D1-D227-423A-B6A6-EA76F880B1F8}\Install\Mp3 Files\0\113'
```

and I am retrieving files using below

```
public static bool versesExists(byte suraNumber, byte reciterID)
        {
            string folderPath = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", @"Mp3 Files\", reciterID, @"\" + suraNumber + @"\");
            int totalSuraAyas = 0;
            using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (storage.DirectoryExists(folderPath))
                {
                    try
                    {

                        DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
                        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.mp3");
                        if (files.Length == totalSuraAyas)
                            return true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

If you see I am checking if the directory exists, then go for files, but it provides me exception in "GetFiles(*.mp3)", I dont know what could be work arund with it?

Comment: I think you have to use the methods on your IsolatedStorageFile instance to gain access to any file system stuff. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02ys433(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank alot, finally got with adding at end of String[] fileNames = isoFile.GetFileNames("Archive\\*");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probable reason is, you are trying to access Isolated storage.

Use the Isolated storage methods like "GetFileNames()" or OpenFile() to access isolate storage files.

Comment: I will accept your reply as answer, I know Mark did provide me enough information for my query.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have space in the folder path.

Mp3 Files should be Mp3Files

```
string folderPath = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", @"Mp3Files\", reciterID, @"\" + suraNumber + @"\");
```