# Is there a way to count isolated storage files in WP8 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, count, isolatedstorage

Is there a way in Windows Phone 8 to count the number of items in the Isolated storage file for an app?
I want to be able to do this so that each file I save can use an integer from the count +1 in the filename.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309390/get-number-of-file-in-folder-in-wp8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to count number of files in isolated storage. One solution to this problem is to use Isolated storage settings to save number files you have created and use this value to create incremental file names.

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

if (!settings.Contains("filesCount"))
{
    settings.Add("filesCount", "1");
    //your file name is "1"
}
else
{
   int count = int.Parse(settings["filesCount"]);
   //name your file
    settings["filesCount"] = (count+1).ToString()
}
settings.Save();
```

Comment: I got this to work but I had to make one change. Instead of int.parse I had to use Convert.ToInt32 but with that change it works great. Thanks